# #FFFAFAFA is not valid value for the system.windows.controls.panel.background

Tags: wpf, xaml

Im just writing my own personal styles.
Everything is ok, no error inside styles.

I have following code

```
<Color x:Key="DialogButtonBorderBrushColor" A="255" R="177" G="177" B="177" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource DialogButtonBorderBrushColor}" />
```

There is a style for my dialog button.

```
<Style x:Key="DialogButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DialogButtonBackgroundColor1}"/>
</Style>
```

Im just using this dialogButtonStyle in xaml Button as a style.
But when I use this style I get following error:

> `#FFFAFAFA` is not a valid value for the System.Windows.Controls.Panel.Background property on setter.

I have really no idea what to do with this.
Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `Resource` key is correct? It says `DialogButtonBackgroundColor1` in your `Style` and `DialogButtonBackgroundColor` in your `Color`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DialogButtonBackgroundColor1}"/>`

`Background` property expects `Brush` value. Judging by the name of resource, `DialogButtonBackgroundColor1` is a `Color`. You should use Brush resource similar to `BorderBrush`

Comment: also, there's a little question where does the error about FFFAFAFA come from and why there is no error about missing `DialogButtonBackgroundColor1` resource. Most probably, somewhere in the project, there is a `DialogButtonBackgroundColor1` resource defined as Color {ARGB=FFFAFAFA} or worse, as String "#FFFAFAFA". That resource should be removed from code as soon as possible to prevent later confusion.